# Error with query over not existing reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have a database, where are tables `User` and `UserDetail`. Relation between tables is `1 : 0..1`. User can have UserDetail.

I am using latest EF model database first.

Problem: when doing query over non existing reference (User dont have a UserDetail)

```
var details = User.UserDetail.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userID == 1)
```

then I am getting error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When User have UserDetail, so everthing is OK.

How to query over non existing reference to get a NULL to var details?

Comment: If you're using C# 6 or above, null conditional operator may help assigning `null`: `var details = User.UserDetail?.FirstOrDefault(u => u.userID == 1)`. For C# 5 or below you need to check against null value for `User.UserDetails` first before using `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: ouu, thanks for fast question, it works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this :

```
User.UserDetail?.FirstOrDefault(...)
```

will return `null` when `User.UserDetail` is `null`, without trying to dereference its value and call a function on it.

`?.` is called the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) or sometimes null-safe navigation operator (or even Elvis operator), for your information.

If `User` can be `null` too, you can use several of these to handle this case :

```
User?.UserDetail?.FirstOrDefault(...)
```